# Count ALL Cells in Range in Excel

Tags: excel, count, range

What's the simplest or preferred Excel formula to count ALL cells in a range, whether blank or not?

Let's say I have a column of cells, some blank and some non-blank. I want a formula displaying "x/y", where x = # of non-blank cells and y= total # of cells.

I found that this will work, but I was wondering if I really need to sum two functions to get "y"?

```
=COUNTA($L$9:$L13) & "/" & COUNTA($L$9:$L13) + COUNTBLANK($L$9:$L13)
```

displays `4/5` (for my data where 4 of the 5 cells are non-blank)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of      `COUNTA($L$9:$L13) + COUNTBLANK($L$9:$L13)`, you can use:

```
=ROWS($L$9:$L13)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about ROWS() (or COLUMNS(), for that matter). Odd that Excel doesn't have CELLS() in case the range has more than one dimension.